# How to add a drop down list of buttons in uinavigation bar in objective c iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, button, uinavigationbar

I am very new to objective c and iPhone applications. I am creating a project in xcode to make an application for iPhone. I need to add a drop down list in the navigation bar of that application. I have added other buttons to it like back button, refresh button. But Now I require a drop down list of buttons/links to it. plz tell me how can I do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this. I'm expanding sabby's solution. just when you add the view with button like a vertical list of buttons. use this code

```
CGRect customViewFrame = yourCustomView.frame;
customViewFrame.size.height = 0;
yourCustomView.frame = customViewFrame;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
customViewFrame.size.height = your_desired_height;
yourCustomView.frame = customViewFrame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Its nice. Bt can you please tell me first that how to add a button of drop down list in navigation bar.

Comment: you need to create a nib or we can say a viewController whose view will look like a list of button. allocate that view controller and display on bottom of navigation controller's bar button with the animation code I gave you.

Comment: This animation is great. But what I did was I added a Table on the top of my view and set the hide property to YES/NO when the button is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Well i think you can use customization,take a view and put the buttons on that view,as many as you want.Then you need to call that view on the click of the button on your navigation bar.
This will resolve your problem.

Comment: It is really a nice solution. But I need a drop down list of buttons on navigation bar as the demand of my client. I have seen a plus button (+) in some example that draws a list to select a particular view. But I didn't understand its code. So can u help me by a sample code

Comment: Well bro you can give the animation for that while adding the subview.You just need to take a view keep the rect small as the size of the button you want and keep the back ground color of the view clear.Then take 3-4 buttons add them to this view.And on the click of you plus button add that as subview and on the click of anybutton on that view remove that view from the superview.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your idea. Bt i will be more thankful to you if u can provide me a sample code or any link that can contain a similar code.

Comment: you can add button like this to the view     
 
  
 
 
 UIButton *Animatebutton=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60, 365, 170, 40)];
 //[Animatebutton setCornerRadius:12];
 [Animatebutton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
 [Animatebutton setTitle:@"Animate" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [[Animatebutton layer]setCornerRadius:16];
 
 [Animatebutton addTarget:self action:@selector(ChangeSize) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [yourviewName addSubview:Animatebutton];